# Need to grep only IP Address

Tags: shell, grep

```
nslookup google.com
Server:         xx.xx.xx.xx
Address:        xx.xx.xxx.xx#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   google.com
Address: 172.217.164.110
```

I just need the last IP Address with grep/awk like below, please help.

```
172.217.164.110
```

Comment: Hope [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/296597/307990) answers your question.

Comment: thanks, yes it helped but it spits all IP address,I only need to fetch only the last IP/ IP's which matches only google.com

Comment: You should add that requirement to the question and while you are at it, you could add some unwanted entry to the sample data and expected output for it and show some work you have already done. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can be enhanced, but it'll do what you want:

```
nslookup google.com | sed -n '/Name:/{x;n;p;d;}; x' | awk '{print $2}'
```

Output (when only one Name+Address block is returned by nslookup):

```
172.217.164.110
```

I used sed's pattern space advanced options, printing the line following the "Name: google.com" line (x;n;p; sequence after "Name:" pattern match). I am not a sed guru, I used [this Unix Stack Exchange answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/206887/219065), then awk to get only the IP following a whitespace.
In a IPv6 setting, you can get both the IPv4 and the IPv6 addresses, in two lines, so if this is not what you want, you will have to filter out the IPv6, using a pattern that only matches the format of an IPv4.